# Is it possible to add kernel symbol dynamically in kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I know there's EXPORT_SYMBOL for kernel modules to expose it's global variables statically.
My question is:
**Is it possible to EXPORT_SYMBOL at runtime?**

I'm developing a kernel driver for multiple IC modules.
There's a global struct list "A" for each IC modules(ko) to add their own IC detection function. And there will be an action to trigger the scanning of "A".
The design is, there is ko(s) for each IC and a main ko for main functions.
For example, there's m1.ko, m2.ko and mm.ko.
I'll insmod m1.ko (create "A" and add it's own detect function),
insmod m2.ko (check "A" existence, if exist, add it's own, if not create "A" and add) and insmod mm.ko (check "A" existence, if exist, trigger the scanning of "A", else do nothing).
I can check kernel symbol "A" by kallsym_lookup_name, but when I came to create "A" if not exist, I can't find a function to add kernel symbol dynamically.

Is there a method to add kernel symbol at runtime correctly? Or there's an alternative way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Please don't do this. Try to change your design to, for example, have the driver modules register and unregister themselves with the main module. They can pass on a struct with function pointers to do initialization or whatnot.

Comment: Hi Jani, thanks for the comment. I've changed the design and will close this question. But I'm curious about why they remove these dynamic kernel symbol create api. Is there some reason behind this?